# Math: Figure details from the summary

Tags: math

If I have played 10 games with a 100% win rate in cruisers and a 50% win rate in battleships and my overall win rate is 60%. How many matches did i play in cruisers?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking to solve a math problem.

Comment: this is just basic algebra.

Comment: For future reference, if you have a pure math question then ask on the math site.  If it does have some programming component, then you are more than welcome to ask here :-)

Comment: @duffymo I fully knew the answer and the equation to get the answer. This was really a question to see how the grammar would affect the outcome of the first answer. I.e. would the first person to answer think there were 10 cruiser games period?

Comment: @rick - nothing I see in your question would suggest to me that you fully knew anything.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about high school algebra, not programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two equations:

```
N_c + N_b = 10          total # games is 10
N_c + 0.5 * N_b = 6     all cruisers were wins, half battleships were wins
```

The first equation can be solved for `N_c` and substituted in the second equation:

```
N_c = 10 - N_b
```

and then substituting this into the second equation gives:

```
N_c + 0.5 * N_b = 6
10 - N_b + 0.5 * N_b = 6
-0.5 * N_b = -4
==> N_b = 8
```

So there were **8 battleships games and 2 cruisers games**.